# exe файл не видит драйвера для sql базы данных. cx_Freeze

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, cx-freeze

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой при создании .exe файла из .py,с помощью cx_Freeze, версии 5.0.2. В своей программе я использую PyQt5, который перекидывается в билд вполне нормально и qsqlite для хранения информации в базе данных. Вот часть кода где происходит непосредственно connection с qsqlite и создание базы данных:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import os
import sqlite3
import _sqlite3
import sqlite3 as lite

def createConnection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(QDir.current().filePath("data.db"))
    if not db.open():
        return False

    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec("create table IF NOT EXISTS product(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
               "date_and_time DATETIME, master VARCHAR(140), service VARCHAR(140), name VARCHAR(140),"
               "Contact_Number VARCHAR(140))"
               )

    return True
```

Суть проблемы в том,что когда я запускаю свой setup файл:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys
import sqlite3 as lite

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files\Python35\tcl\tk8.6'


build_exe_options = {"packages": [
  'os','sys','sqlite3'], 'include_files': [os.path.join(sys.base_prefix, 'DLLs', 'sqlite3.dll'), 'main.py','util.py','data.db']}

setup(
    name = "Eclients",
    version = "0.1",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("main.py")]
)
```

Всё происходит успешно,но при запуске .exe файла,получаю вот такое сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа просто не видит драйвера для sql,и соответственно выдаёт ошибку.Хотя в самой папке build они присутствуют.
Я работаю на Windows 10(x64),Python 3.5.4
Как можно решить эту проблему? в сумме за два дня потратил на поиск ответа около 15 часов,но поиски не увенчались успехом, также задавал этот же вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему путём копирования целой папки sqldrivers из
`C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins`
в директорию с .exe файлом.